# PHP Pear gives 500 error in browser

Tags: php, pear

I have pear installed and can run this:

`<?php
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>`

in the command line perfectly.
(got this: `bool(true)`)

But when I try to run the same code via the browser I am getting a 500 error. Also phpstorm cannot find the file System.php

I already tried restarting my server and nothing happened.
I need to be able to use Pear via the browser.

Comment: A 500 error typically has an error *message* attached, either on the page or in the logs somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that PHP CLI and php_mod/PHP-FPM have separate configurations (php.ini files). How to check if the pear is working: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all I had to do was put

```
php_value include_path ".:/usr/share/pear"
```

in .htaccess